# Reading characters from a text file and storing in a 2D array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Stupid question, but I am panicking.
How would I go about reading characters from a text file (including spaces) and storing them in a 2D array.

I know I need to use something involving (say I have a 2D array file[50][50])

```
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF);

file[50][50] = characterWithinFile
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I (surprisingly) know what I need to do after this point. Thanks

Comment: Try removing the semicolon after the while, which is preventing your loop from actually executing any statements, and replacing characterWithinFile with the "ch" variable you used to store the character.  If this does not work, we need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is some code that can help you

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
FILE *fopen(), *fp;
char c;
int i=0,j=0;
char file[50][50];
fp = fopen("file.txt","r");
c = getc(fp) ;
while (c!= EOF)
{
file[i][j]=c;

    j++;
    c = getc(fp);

    if(j==50){
    i++;
    j=0;
    }
}
fclose(fp);
}
```

and please choose a higher number than 50 if your text is more than 2500 characters !