# How to read data from file into 2-D array?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, file-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading characters from a text file and storing in a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887497/reading-characters-from-a-text-file-and-storing-in-a-2d-array)

I wish to know how one can read data from a txt file, into a 2-d array. The requirements are:-
1. the first line has a number which needs to be assigned to a variable.
2. the lines that follow have to be read into a 2-d array, such that every time a '\n' is encountered in the line, a next row is to be taken and fed data. This needs to be done till EOF is reached. File Handling is a little complex for me, an hence Im having problems with it. Thankyou.

Comment: It seems you want us to write some code for you. What have *you* tried?

Comment: What is the size of each line or row?  And why this line in your question? the first line has a number which needs to be assigned to a variable.

Comment: home work? pls share the code and tell where you have a problem

Comment: I have actually written code for it, although like i said i have trouble with file handling so my code is pretty wrong. For proofs sake, ill post it.

Answer (score 0):

Use fscanf. That is all you need to know. Please google before you post questions.